# Why is the Terminal Prompt asking for a password when I try to install Homebrew?

Tags: terminal, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am installing Homebrew through my Terminal and when I enter the code given and press Return the Terminal asks for a password but I am unable to type it. The following is the script I pasted into the Terminal Prompt:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSLhttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

[image: Terminal screen shot]

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: You're not "unable to type". It's reading your password fine, but just not showing you for security reasons. You're getting that error because you didn't type the right password

Comment: Thank you Joseph. My problem is that I don't know what password to enter.

Comment: The one for your macOS account?

Comment: Super thank you,..will try that !

Answer (score 4):

The question is naive but a problem exists: **when Homebrew asks for the password, sometimes it does it multiple times consecutively**.

It does it because it needs it multiple times, but to the user (due to the lack of messages) it feels like the password inserted is wrong. It's not, you just need to input it again, and again, and again.

When the password is wrong, it says:

> Sorry, try again.

But you don't know it if you always input it correctly.

Just a bad command line user experience.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Password is not shown for security reasons. You are typing it but you don't see neither dots nor your password. Just type the passowrd and press <kbd>Return</kbd> (Enter) (but you will see nothing before you press <kbd>Return</kbd>). It is de facto standard for terminal applications.

Answer (score 0):

Any password you will type will be invisible. The password is your login password/administrator password.

Firstly, it was showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv045.png)

But when we enter our admin/login password, then it proceeds further.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDEMw.png)

Answer (score 0):

it will not show, but it is actually inputing, just enter the correct password and then press enter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).